# Removing default padding in listview items within Android studio

Tags: android, xml, listview, user-interface

Can someone provide me with any insights on how to remove the default padding around a listview item? I have provided an image with arrows indicating what padding I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom a custom layout file for your list items. And a custom adapter. Then you can control all the appearance.